# Error in conversion date from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I'm trying to do a dynamic table, in which, number of columns depends on range of dates. So, I'm trying to use a pivot table. Every time I run the query I've got this error:

`Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 18`
`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

This is the query (MSSQL):

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME  
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME  
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)  
DECLARE @Str_Dates NVARCHAR(MAX)  

SET @StartDate = '2014-05-01'
SET @EndDate = '2014-05-16'

SELECT  @Str_Dates = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT
                    '],[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CreateDate,111)
                    FROM myDB.dbo.SaleTransaction
                    WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
                    ORDER BY 1 
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 2, '') 
                    + ']'

SET @Query = 
'SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT CreateDate AS [DATE], ItemID, Description, SUM(Quantity) AS [QTY]
FROM myDB.dbo.SaleTransactionDetails
WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN '+@StartDate+' AND '+@EndDate+'
GROUP BY CreateDate, ItemID, Description
) tpvt     
PIVOT (SUM(tpvt.QDE) FOR tpvt.DATE
IN ('+@Str_Dates+')) AS pvt'

EXECUTE (@Query)
```

If I remove `WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN '+@StartDate+' AND '+@EndDate+'` the query runs without problems. So, I try use `CONVERT` function in several ways to convert the variables into Dates but without success.
Any idea what I can do to use this variables and don't have that error?

Comment: Try `CAST(@StartDate as DATE )` instead of @StartDate.

Comment: I change to: `WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN '+CAST(@StartDate AS DATE)+' AND '+CAST(@EndDate AS DATE)+'` AND it gives-me: `The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.`

Comment: `CAST` is SQL so try something like `WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN '+ 'CAST('+@StartDate+ ' AS DATE)' + ' AND ' + 'CAST(' + @EndDate + ' AS DATE)'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN '+@StartDate+'`

You cannot concatenate (+) a string to a datetime.

Convert it to a **quoted** string in your dynamic SQL:

```
'CreateDate BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @StartDate, 112) + ''' AND ...
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex. I've tried both `CONVERT`AND `CAST`with success. Only needed a quoted string. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SET @StartDate = convert(datetime,'2014-05-01')
SET @EndDate = convert(datetime,'2014-05-16')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In TSQL, date/time are presented as string and string is enclosed by single quote mark.
2. Use two single quote mark to escape single quote mark inside a string.

So modify your code to

```
'WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN '''+@StartDate+''' AND '''+ @EndDate+ '''
```